# I would like to know how i am meant to put a loop in this simple dice game in C

Tags: c, dice

I would like to know the best way to loop this code. Basically it's a dice game which draws a random number between 1 and 6. Once the number is displayed to the player I would like to give them the option "would you like to play again?" and if they type y or yes then the game restarts. I'm guessing I should use a while loop but I'm not sure how to go about that. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
main() {
   int lower = 1, upper = 6, count = 1;
   srand(time(0)); 
   generate_random(lower, upper, count);
 }
void generate_random(int l, int r, int count) { 
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      int rand_num = (rand() % (r - l + 1)) + l;
      printf("You rolled a %d", rand_num);
   }
}
```

Comment: A `while` loop would be the correct solution. You put the loop around the part you want to repeat. It seems you know what that part is already, and what you want the loop to do.  You should be able to work out where that should go yourself.

Comment: Like around `generate_random(lower, upper, count);` in `main()` would seem like a likely place. I would recommend a small buffer, `64`-chars or so and taking input with `fgets()` and then comparing the first character of input to ensure you consume the complete user-input (including the `'\n'` generated by pressing **Enter**) E.g. `char buf[64] = ""; while (*buf != 'n' && *buf != 'N') { generate_random (lower, upper, count); fputs ("\nwould you like to roll again (y/n)? ", stdout); if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) break; }` You should specify `int main (void)` if you take no parameters.

Comment: If you want to do something at least once and then potentially repeat it, then using a `do {} while ();` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is apparent you want to prompt and allow the user to "roll-again". In your code, what is it that does the roll? That is what you want to loop. In `main()` that would seem to be:

```
    generate_random(lower, upper, count);
```

Now when you apply your `while` loop or a `do ... while();` loop, care must be taken in how you take your input. You can simply `getchar()`, but you would need to account for the `'\n'` generated by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, otherwise you would appear to skip a prompt when `getchar()` happily took `'\n'` as your next input. (and what if the user enters `"Yes again!"`?)

All new C programmers should take user-input using `fgets()` and a buffer sufficient to hold the expected contents of the line (minimum 32-chars, or 2X max expected input as a rough rule-of-thumb). That way even if the user enters `"Yes again!"`, all characters are read into the buffer and consumed -- including the `'\n'`.

You can easily just check the 1st character of the character-array used as the buffer by simply dereferencing the buffer, e.g.

```
char buf[64] = "";
```

Then to check the 1st char in buffer you can use:

```
*buf == 'n'
```

How does that work?

```
*buf == *(buf + 0) == buf[0]
```

So you are just checking the character at the first index of the array.

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXC 64     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

void generate_random(int l, int r, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("You rolled a %d\n", rand() % (r - l + 1) + l);
}

int main (void) {
    
    int lower = 1, upper = 6, count = 1;
    char buf[MAXC] = "";                        /* array of 64 chars to use as a buffer */
                                                /* to hold the user-input */        
    srand(time(0));
    
    while (*buf != 'n' && *buf != 'N') {        /* loop while 1st char not 'n' or 'N' */
        generate_random(lower, upper, count);
        
        fputs ("\nwould you like to roll again (y/n)? ", stdout);   /* prompt again */
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))     /* read user-input & validate read */
            break;                              /* if user generates EOF break */
    }
}
```

A `do .. while();` loop would eliminate the need to initialize `buf` as the empty-string with `buf[MAXC] = "";` (which initializes the 1st character `0` explicitly and then the remaining 63-characters to `0` by default)

**Exaple Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/diceagain
You rolled a 3

would you like to roll again (y/n)? y
You rolled a 2

would you like to roll again (y/n)? Yes please again!
You rolled a 4

would you like to roll again (y/n)? Sure one more time...
You rolled a 4

would you like to roll again (y/n)? n
```

So long as the user doesn't enter more than 63-characters of input -- you will have no problem with extraneous characters being left unread on `stdin`.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.